# SLF4J error while starting the Hbase in standalone mode

Tags: hbase

while starting the hbase (in stand-alone mode) with ./bin/start-hbase.sh in the hbase directory, 
I get the following error,

```
saichanda@saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:/usr/local/hbase$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh 
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-saichanda-master-saichanda-OptiPlex-9020.out
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
```

How to resolve this error?

My hbase-site.xml file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:80/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

zookeeper is running... while running hbase I get the error...
In hbase-env.sh, I have

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

How to resolve my error starting hbase??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have given wrong configuration in hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>{absolute_directory_path}</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Try with these values.

Comment: what is `{absolute directory path}`. Is it where I want my zookeeper logs be saved/stored?

Comment: It is the absolute directory path where zk stores its snapshots and transnational logs.